# Xamarin, Android - Service stop working when I close aplication

Tags: android, xamarin, service

I'm trying to make android service to checking device location in background. Service should works all the time from start to moment when user or specific condition in code will stop it.

And service is working fine up to the time when I close application, then service stop and crash application.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CheckPositionService))]
namespace GNote.Droid.Models
{
    [Service(Name = "GNote.Service", Exported = true)]
    public class CheckPositionService : Service, IMapService
    {
        private CheckPositionServiceBinder binder;
        private CheckPositionServiceConnection ServiceConnection;
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        this.startCheckingPosition();
        var ongoing = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.icon, "Test");
        StartForeground(1000, ongoing);
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            binder = new CheckPositionServiceBinder(this);           
            return binder;
        }

        public void StartServ()
        {
            Android.MainActivity.AndroidContext.StartService(new Intent(Android.MainActivity.AndroidContext, typeof(CheckPositionService)));
        }
```

Class MapPosition.

```
public static class MapPosition
    {
        private static List<Note> notes;

        public static async void getFromDB()
        {
            notes = await DataBaseService.getMapAlarmActiveNotes();
            if (notes.Count == 0)
            {
                await StopListening();               
            }
            else
            {
                await StartListening();                
            }

        }

        public static async Task StartListening()
        {            
            if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
                return;

            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10, true);

            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += PositionChanged;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += PositionError;
        }

        private static void PositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
        {

            sendNotification(e.Position.Longitude+" POS "+e.Position.Latitude);

        }

        private static async void PositionError(object sender, PositionErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            await StopListening();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
            //Handle event here for errors
            await StartListening();
        }

        public static async Task StopListening()
        {
            if (!CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
                return;

            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync();

            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged -= PositionChanged;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError -= PositionError;
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use a foreground service: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/foreground-services/

Comment: It works fine with API25 but with API 23 I have deployment error. Any idea how to fix it? Code updated above.